# What is the method "backgroundRect(forBounds:)" of UIButton used for?

Tags: swift, uibutton, cgrect

I found out that `UIButton` has a `backgroundRect(forBounds:)` function, but I can not understand where and how can I use it.

I also cannot understand how can I use the `contentRect(forBounds:)`, `titleRect(forContentRect:)` and `imageRect(forContentRect:)` methods. Please, explain me.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624015-backgroundrect Looks like bounds

Comment: Apple says `Returns the rectangle in which the receiver draws its background.`

Comment: I read the documentation. But all the same I can not imagine a situation in which I will need to address this function.

Answer (score 2):

By default, `backgroundRect(forBounds:)` returns the **same value** as `bounds`. However, you can override it in a subclass to prevent drawing over your custom content.

From [Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624015-backgroundrect):

> The default implementation of this method returns the value in the bounds parameter. This rectangle represents the area in which the button draws its standard background content. Subclasses that provide custom background adornments can override this method and return a modified bounds rectangle to prevent the button from drawing over any custom content.

`contentRect(forBounds:)` returns the area that is used for displaying the title and the image of the button.

`titleRect(forContentRect:)` and `imageRect(forContentRect:)` return the rectangle of the title/image.

Here is some visual help for the return value of all four of these methods for a non-overridden, standard button:

[image: visual representation of the return value of the methods mentioned above]

Answer (score 1):

> But all the same I can not imagine a situation in which I will need to address this function

Then imagine this: a button that appears to shrink a little in response to being tapped, as feedback to the user, growing back to its normal size when the user's finger is no longer on the button. How would you do it? Here's an elegant way:

```
extension CGSize {
    func sizeByDelta(dw:CGFloat, dh:CGFloat) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width:self.width + dw, height:self.height + dh)
    }
}
class MyShrinkingButton: UIButton {
    override func backgroundRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var result = super.backgroundRect(forBounds:bounds)
        if self.isHighlighted {
            result = result.insetBy(dx: 3, dy: 3)
        }
        return result
    }
    override var intrinsicContentSize : CGSize {
        return super.intrinsicContentSize.sizeByDelta(dw:25, dh: 20)
    }
}
```

The effect is subtle but lively and clear. Here is the button in its normal state and in its highlighted state.

[image]
[image]

Comment: That's great! But unfortunately I did not manage to apply this code. Xcode returns an error in the third line: Argument labels '(_:, _:)' do not match any available overloads

Comment: Thanks. Fixed! Should compile now.

Comment: It is compiled. But I do not see a visual effect. I created a button of type MyShrinkingButton. And when I click on it in the simulator nothing happens.

Comment: Obviously I have no idea what _you_ are doing. Here's the actual downloadable example, which works as advertised: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/61f0c753a080040e4a74b912e6c18dd97fe8bcaa/bk2ch12p595button

Comment: I found out what went wrong: backgroundRect works only if we use backgroundImage, but my button had only backgroundColor. So it seems the method should be called backgroundImageRect instead of backgroundRect. Anyway, now everything works fine. Thanks for the great idea.