# Apply corner radius to the decreasing button

Tags: swift, uibutton, shadow, cornerradius

I have a very good-looking button.

```
import UIKit
class NiseButtonVC: UIViewController {
var button = MyShrinkingButton()
var button2 = UIButton()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    button = MyShrinkingButton()
    button.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 80)

    button.center = view.center
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)


    button.setTitle("button", for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 40)
    button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    let backGroundImage = UIImage.from(color: .orange)
    button.setBackgroundImage(backGroundImage, for: .normal)
    button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
//        button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
//        button.layer.masksToBounds = true
    view.addSubview(button)
 }
@objc func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton){
    print("button pressed")

}
}

extension CGSize {
func sizeByDelta(dw:CGFloat, dh:CGFloat) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width:self.width + dw, height:self.height + dh)
}
}
class MyShrinkingButton: UIButton {

override func backgroundRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    var result = super.backgroundRect(forBounds:bounds)
    if self.isHighlighted {
        result = result.insetBy(dx: 3, dy: 3)
    }
    return result
}
override var intrinsicContentSize : CGSize {
    return super.intrinsicContentSize.sizeByDelta(dw:25, dh: 20)
}

override func titleRect(forContentRect bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    var result = super.titleRect(forContentRect:bounds)
    if self.isHighlighted {
        result = result.insetBy(dx: 3, dy: 3)
    }
    return result
}

}

extension UIImage {
static func from(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    context!.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
    context!.fill(rect)
    let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return img!
}
}
```

But I want the button to have rounded edges. I can do it using cornerRadius for .normal state, but when button is pressed the effect disappears. In truth I would like to add shadow to the button, and I can add shadow itself, but I have no idea how to combine shadow and rounded edges.

**looks now**

[image: looks now]

**I want to see**

[image: I want to see]

I can not use button.backgroundColor instead of button.setBackgroundColor, because then the button will not decrease when you click. This I found out a couple of weeks ago:
[What is the method "backgroundRect(forBounds:)" of UIButton used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50737542/what-is-the-method-backgroundrectforbounds-of-uibutton-used-for)

Final code. Only shadow don't work. But the corner radius also work only fro viewDidLoad:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var button = ShrinkingButton()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    button = ShrinkingButton()
    button.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 80)

    button.center = view.center
    button.setTitle("button", for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 40)
    button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    button.backgroundColor = .orange
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    button.layer.masksToBounds = true
    view.addSubview(button)
}
}


class ShrinkingButton: UIButton {

override var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
            self.isHighlighted ?     self.layer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9 )) :
                self.layer.setAffineTransform(.identity)
        }
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    layer.cornerRadius = 10

    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 2)
    layer.shadowRadius = 5
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
}
}
```

Comment: Please show, how's your button should looks ?

Comment: I tried to add images. But the whole code is here. If you launch it now, I will see how it looks. If you uncomment line 21 and 22, you will see how it should look like. But the button should keep the proportions when you click.

Comment: For this, you can use normal button and set background colour for same. It's very easy and preferable instead of creating custom class.

Comment: Hi, zombie’s answer could be correct. Does your problem exist now?

Comment: No, I can not. Normal button with background color will not decrease when pressed.

Comment: Honestly, it's not a _"very good-looking button"_. It's just an OK looking button.

Comment: remove this line `button.layer.masksToBounds = true`

Comment: @zombie, I tried this already. It does not help. Also if I delete the previous line: "button.layer.cornerRadius = 10", there will be no rounded corners. So, I think the problem is somewhere in "override func awakeFromNib()"

Answer (score 1):

The button disappears because you set the background image to the normal state only.

That means for any other state the button does not have a background image.

A better approach would be to set the background color instead of the image

```
button.backgroundColor = .orange
```

If you want to use a background image which is not just a color then maybe you can use this

```
button.setBackgroundImage(image, for: UIControlState())
```

To create a shrinking effect on press with showdow

```
import UIKit

class ShrinkingButton: UIButton {

    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
                self.isHighlighted ? self.layer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9 )) :
                self.layer.setAffineTransform(.identity)
            }
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        layer.cornerRadius = 10

        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 2)
        layer.shadowRadius = 5
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I tried UIControlState(), and it still don't work. With utton.backgroundColor = .orange the button will not even decrease when pressed.

Comment: @Sergey check my updated answer for making the button shrink (should work with background color and layer.cornerRadius)

Comment: Yes, it works.  Thank you. But there are a couple of nuances. The button reacts a bit slower - at first I thought it sounded, but really a bit slower. Of course this is not a problem in general. Also I do not see the title of the button, although it is set.

Comment: @Sergey I made it a little bit faster by changing the duration also the animation is inside the override now

Comment: Really. I did not notice "UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1)" :(  It's much better now. But I still can not see the title.

Comment: And is there any way to add a shadow to this button?

Comment: @Sergey that should be another question but anyway I updated the answer again

Comment: Thank you very much @zombie. Your decision for the button itself with the is very elegant. But I can not see the shadow. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong by calling a button.

Comment: upload a sample to github

Comment: can I just add the code to my first question? There is only one page there.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this code works

```
import UIKit

class NiseButtonwhithShadowVC: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // constants
    let radius: CGFloat = 20, dimension: CGFloat = 200, offset = 4
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50)

    // custom view
    let customView = ShrinkingButton2(frame: frame)
    customView.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)

    // image layer
    let imageLayer = CALayer()
    imageLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
    imageLayer.masksToBounds = true
    imageLayer.frame = frame
    imageLayer.cornerRadius = radius
    imageLayer.masksToBounds = true

    // rounded layer
    let roundedLayer = CALayer()
    roundedLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    roundedLayer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: dimension, height: 50), cornerRadius: radius).cgPath
    roundedLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: offset, height: offset)
    roundedLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    roundedLayer.shadowRadius = 2
    roundedLayer.frame = frame

    // views and layers hierarchy
    customView.layer.addSublayer(imageLayer)
    customView.layer.insertSublayer(roundedLayer, below: imageLayer)
    view.addSubview(customView)

    // layout
    customView.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.midX, y: view.bounds.midY)

}

}

class ShrinkingButton2: UIButton {

override var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
            self.isHighlighted ? self.layer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.95, y: 0.95 )) :
                self.layer.setAffineTransform(.identity)
        }
    }
}

}
```

Thanks to everyone who helped me.